# Simple style change does not apply

Tags: less, themes, magento2

I've followed the first part of [this guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html) by:

1. Creating and applying my own theme.
2. Using the `web/css/source/_extend.less` that's on the guide.
3. Deleting the mentioned directories.
4. Refreshing the page.

But the button style did not change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to admin, go to **System -> Cache Management** in the bottom of the page you could see the three flush cache button option. click the JS/css and static flush cache button then clear the cache of your browser also. load the page it will get reflect.

have good luck