# magento 2 styles.css isn't created in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

The styles.css isn't created in the homepage and the console indicates a 404 error message: %7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstyles.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

I use a a shared hosting with no subfolder. 
I have already tried to change permissions, also the apache rewrite is activated on the server and the content:deploy. Any idea what else could I try?

Thanks

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454314/simple-style-change-does-not-apply/36510694#36510694

Comment: thanks for it, I tried it but it didn't work. Any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: `cd /var/www/html/Magento2`

Step 2: `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/*  var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*`

Step 3: `chmod 777 pub -R`

Step 4: `chmod 777 var -R`

Step 5: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Step 6: `Repeat step 3&4.`

Comment: Where you included the file and location of the css file ?

Comment: I guess that the css file should be in pub/media/ but there is no css file, I'm using the Luma-template and have in the backend /html head: <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" />

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing sample data. It is fixed after running the setup:upgrade

> php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade